# Generate PDF file more than one page in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, paging

I'm trying to generate a PDF file that have more than one page. I'm using this code :

```
-(void)createPDFfromUI:(UIWebView *)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
{
    // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted

    UIWebView *myView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];

    [myView setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480)];

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, myView.bounds, nil);

    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

        aView.layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0,480* -i , 320, 480);

        [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

    }

    [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

    // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES]; 
}
```

The problem with this code is , it just generate a PDF file with 4 similar pages and they are all the last 480 px of my original page. (aView) Also when I move `[aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext]; line out of the FOR loop it generates a PDF file with 4 pages but the first 3 pages will be blank and the last page has some data.

Do you guys have any idea how can i solve this problem ?!

Comment: Hey Dude  [myView setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480)]; is always fixed dude......

Comment: Hey @Manohar ! Yeah I know , that is size of each page in my PDF file. I dont have problem with that, The problem is that my data in all pages are similar !

Comment: can i ask one thing ?-(void)createPDFfromUI:(UIWebView *)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
 how many times this method w'l call?

Comment: That should call only one time @Sunny the thing is he should write   UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, myView.bounds, nil);
 CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); these in for loop.. You need to take the pdfContext for each page

Comment: Thanks @Manohar but when I put them in the for loop, it just generated one page. I think if i put the UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, myView.bounds, nil); line in the loop it just shows the last loop.

Comment: See your myView.bounds is alwawz same rite ? so write that also inside for loop and set the bounds i mean y position @Rudi

Comment: Yeah right but since I put myView.bounds in the for loop, my PDF file becomes one page. @Manohar

Comment: What did you put inside the for loop ?? Could you pls paste here ?

Comment: Sure @Manohar : for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        
        [myView setBounds:CGRectMake(0,480* i , 320, 480)];
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, myView.bounds, nil);
        
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        
        aView.layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 480*-i , 320, 480);

        CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
        
    }

Comment: instead of this  480*-i, put same as 480*i and check @Rudi

Answer (score 1):

bounds means the position of the layer in it's parent. so when you render a layer, it uses it's `frame` to determine it's contents.
You have to place the view as a subview in another view such as `aView2`. then set the bounds of the `aView` just like you already did, then render `aView2` instead.

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

add string array and try refreshing the app

you must also add the physical pdf file to you xcode project
you can do this by dragging and dropping it into the left hand menu browsing

another method could be used is accessing pdf remotley using URL

click run and see if it works

hope this helps